# Facebook Graph API getAccessToken() / Access token expiration

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm going to be writing a Facebook Graph script/application that will run as a cron.  I tried to do this before, but it said that the access token expired. I tried using `getAccessToken()`, but it told me that a valid access token had to be used to request information about the current user. How can I automatically renew my access token so my cron job won't break?

Answer (score 0):

The normal access token expires in 2 hours, and the extended token lasts for 2 months. 
For the extended token guide, go though this: [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036)

Now, the best thing you can do is to update regularly this extended token of the user when he log-in the app/website. So, you can use this token in your cron job. This will fail only when the user didn't visit your app for 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify expiry of your access token at below link?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Moreover, you can get detailed answer by visiting similar question:

[How to renew/extend facebook access tokens with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021892/how-to-renew-extend-facebook-access-tokens-with-php)