# How to permanently connect with fb account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi I want to create a feauture for my cms. It should work like this:
When user publish news on website it will automatically publish a link on Facebook page.

What is the best solution ? Let's say we have one facebook account but multiple website admins. And permanent access token doesnt exists so I will have to do some reauthentication?

Any tips how to make this work will be very apriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of last month facebook removed offline access and the access token you use will work for only 60 days. In order to use it after that period you will have to renew access token every time your user enters your web page or whatever you have. 
Take a look at this link 
[How to renew/extend facebook access tokens with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021892/how-to-renew-extend-facebook-access-tokens-with-php)